# Java Program Organization: How can I get rid of this massive case statement?

Tags: java, architecture, oop, switch-statement

I am creating a program that will fill in a given grammar.  Right now I am modeling the "kinds of words" like this:

```
public class WordDescriptor {

    public static final String noun = "N";
    public static final String plural = "p";
    public static final String nounPhrase = "h";
    public static final String usuParticipleVerb = "V";
    public static final String transitiveVerb = "t";
    public static final String intransitiveVerb = "i";
    public static final String adjective = "A";
    public static final String adverb = "v";
    public static final String conjunction = "C";
    public static final String preposition = "P";
    public static final String interjection = "!";
    public static final String pronoun = "r";
    public static final String definiteArticle = "D";
    public static final String indefiniteArticle = "I";
    public static final String nominative = "o";
    public static final String defaultTag = "?";

    private String word; // where word is one of the constants defined above.  

    public String getWord(){
        return word;
    }

    public String setWord(){
        return word;
    }

    /** For debugging only.  
     * 
     * @param s
     * @return
     */
    protected static String getKind(String s){
        if(s.equals(noun)){
            return "noun";
        }else if(s.equals(plural)){
            return "plural";
        }else if(s.equals(nounPhrase)){
            return "nounPhrase";
        }else if(s.equals(usuParticipleVerb)){
            return "usuParticipleVerb";
        }else if(s.equals(transitiveVerb)){
            return "transitiveVerb";
        }else if(s.equals(intransitiveVerb)){
            return "intransitiveVerb";
        }else if(s.equals(adjective)){
            return "adjective";
        }else if(s.equals(adverb)){
            return "adverb";
        }else if(s.equals(conjunction)){
            return "conjunction";
        }else if(s.equals(preposition)){
            return "preposition";
        }else if(s.equals(interjection)){
            return "interjection";
        }else if(s.equals(pronoun)){
            return "pronoun";
        }else if(s.equals(definiteArticle)){
            return "definiteArticle";
        }else if(s.equals(indefiniteArticle)){
            return "indefiniteArticle";
        }else if(s.equals(nominative)){
            return "nominative";
        } else if(s.equals(defaultTag)){
            return "defaultTag";
        }else{
            return "other: "+s;
        }
    }

}
```

This is pretty much the most ugly code that I can imagine.  I know I can make it a bit better by using a case statement however that is still friggin ugly.  Here is my question:

How can I make it beautiful?  I was thinking about making:

- class WordDescriptor, with subclasses:

  - class noun, with subclasses:

    - singular
    - plural
  - class verb
  - class adverb

But I am not sure if this seems like a great idea either.  How can I this out better?

---

Edit: If I did take the second approach I am not even sure what the classes would look like.  Here is an example:

```
public abstract class WordDescriptor {

   public String toString();

}

public class Noun extends WordDescriptor {

    public String toString(){
        return "Noun";
    }
}

public class Plural extends Noun{
    public String toString(){
        return "Plural";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do something with an enumerated type.

```
public enum SpeechPart
{
    NOUN ("noun"),
    PLURAL ("plural"),
    NOUNPHRASE ("noun phrase"),
    ADVERB ("adverb"),
    ADJECTIVE ("adjective"),
    CONJUNCTION ("conjunction"),
    VERB ("verb");

    private String english;

    SpeechPart(String inEnglish)
    {
        this.english = inEnglish;
    }

    public String toString() { return english; }
}
```

You can now assign these to a variable.

```
SpeechPart dog = SpeechPart.NOUN;
SpeechPart ran = SpeechPart.VERB;
SpeechPart quickly = SpeechPart.ADVERB;
```

And then you can see what their parts of speech are:

```
System.out.println(dog.toString());
System.out.println(quickly);        // Implicit call to toString()
```

This solution assumes only a single part of speech per word. To allow for modifiers, such as "first person," "third person," "plural," "present," "progressive," etc., you could simply enumerate all of them -- a tedious job but need be done only once. Alternatively, you could adapt the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), which addresses specifically the need to add attributes to an object dynamically.

Another suggestion is enumerate the modifiers:

```
public enum SpeechModifier
{
    SINGULAR,
    PLURAL,
    FIRST_PERSON,
    SECOND_PERSON,
    THIRD_PERSON,
    PRESENT,
    PAST,
    PERFECT,
    PROGRESSIVE;
}
```

Then build a class that combines them together:

```
public class Word
{
    String word;
    SpeechPart part;
    EnumSet<SpeechModifier> modifiers;
}
```

Now you can model a whole word:

```
Word w1 = new Word();
w1.word = "bouncing";
w1.part = SpeechPart.VERB;
w1.modifiers = EnumSet<SpeechModifier>.of(SpeechModifier.PRESENT, SpeechModifier.PROGRESSIVE);
```

This solution, however, doesn't prevent non-sensical combinations, such as FIRST_PERSON NOUN PAST.

Comment: I think that this is a good idea HOWEVER, it does not address that there are some words that have subcategories.  Ie: a noun can be singular or plural.

Comment: Your original solution doesn't address that, either. I'll add some notes to point you in some appropriate directions.

Answer (score 12):

I would just create a dictionary or map from abbreviation to full description. Then `getKind` would look up its input in the mapping and return the result, or `other` if the input doesn't map to anything.

Comment: I think that this is a good idea HOWEVER, it does not address that there are some words that have subcategories.  Ie: a noun can be singular or plural.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Nor does your original solution. `getKind(String s)` function, s is simply compared to each of the constants. Did you intend to post the code to retrieve `s` before it is passed to `getKind()`?

Comment: In order to support multiple subcategories, you could just use a list of descriptors (or a string: "Npo" would describe a plural nominative noun). Or you could create a bunch of subcategories (like Case, Gender, Tense, Person, Declension, etc.) and assign them to a `List<Subcategory>` that's part of each word.

Answer (score 2):

Could you use a dictionary with the code (`s` in your case) as the key and the returned string as the value?

Comment: simplest solution, is nearly always the best